# how can i check or update unreal apk api?

Tags: android, apk, unreal-engine4

You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs or Android App Bundles.

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. Learn more about signing.

Your app currently targets API level 26 and must target at least API level 28 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 28. Learn how.

this is proplem i met when i upload my game to google play

Comment: You have to follow the app signing process. Please checkout https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: There are 3 issue here; 1- You should sign your apk with appropriate keystore(you can create it) 2- While generating apk  be sure you selected release radio button 3- Change you targetSDK version to 28 (but you have to update android support libs to same version as well)

Answer (score 0):

There is APK verification command in Android development tool, by which you can verify exact signature and APK details. Below is the documentation details

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner

Use console command:

apksigner verify --print-certs

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your build.gradle. make sure release build does not have debuggable true.
2. Create and use new keystore for uploading apk/bundle to play store. Do not use debug keystore which comes bydefault.
3. Target SDk version of app/game should be atleast 28, else playstore will not allow you to upload the apk/bundle.